# Content of /proc/pid/maps

Tags: linux, process, virtual-memory

When I print the contents of the running process, I got result like this

```
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 137910                             /home/user/process/a.out
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 08:01 137910                             /home/user/process/a.out
02434000-02455000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
```

Why the a.out is loaded at two memory regions? Is it the same part or different parts. One has got `r-xp` and other has got `rw-p`. Eventhough I have allocated a size of integer using malloc in the program, the size of the heap is shown more than that. Why is it so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `r-xp` region at 0x400000 is your text (code) section. It's readable, and executable, but not writable.

The `rw-p` region at 0x600000 is your data section. It's readable and writable, but not executable.

[`readelf -S a.out`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readelf) will show you the sections in your executable, and where they are going to be loaded into memory (first through a section-to-segment mapping.)

---

Your experiment about `malloc`ing 4 bytes is insufficient, because that's not how memory management works.  When you call `malloc`, your libc implementation is going to carve out a small piece out of the large pool that it is maintaining. (This is just *your process* doing this - the OS is not immediately involved.) When you have depleted that pool, it will use the `brk` (or `mmap`) system call to ask the kernel to give it more memory.

If you `malloc` a much larger amount of memory, you will probably see the heap grow.  Also, you can run `strace` on your executable, and see when it actually makes the `brk` or `memmap` system calls.